# Using VertexDelete to remove vertices by degree

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to remove vertices that have degree less than 2, but I think I am missing something basic.

I was hoping that I could use:

`VertexDelete[g, VertexDegree[#] < 2 & ]`

But it seems that this is not supported in a few ways.

1. I know that I can operate on one vertex at a time from the examples, but that seems to use pattern matching, rather than a pure function. I tried using `_?(VertexDegree[#] < 2 &)` instead as the pure function, but there still is a bigger issue
2. The `VertexDegree` does not have an overload that just takes a "vertex" object. For that matter, I don't even know *what* is being matched in the `VertexDelete` function. Is it the label of the node only?

I sense I am missing something basic about this whole process. Any pointers?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you mean why this is a "hard" problem, or meaning I can corrupt my graph accidentally?

Comment: I successfully deleted VertexDegree < 2 vertices from VertexList[g] and re-inserted the smaller list into a graph using the prior EdgeList[g] and had problems.  The answer below, using VertexDelete automatically recomputes the EdgeList, and hence is superior to my approach.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 4},   VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
VertexDegree[g]
(* {2, 3, 2, 1} *)

VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] < 2 &)]
```

[image]

You can also use `KCoreComponents[g, 2]` to find the vertices whose vertex degree at least 2 and use it with `Subgraph`:

```
Subgraph[g, KCoreComponents[g, 2], VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

> same picture

Comment: I hate being this close to an answer, but thank you very much.

Comment: @soandos, i know the feeling:) Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
VertexDelete[g, Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], d_ /; d < 2]]
```

which I expect to have better performance, but I haven't benchmarked.

Comment: On a graph of about ~100K nodes, the other approach takes about a second. If I need more performance, I'll try it out.